# How to inspect an intent to see if it was an intent that started/launched the app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, android-navigation-graph

How to inspect an intent to see if it was an intent that started/launched the app versus an intent that was used to navigate from within the app or once the app was already opened?

We have special UI handling based on if the intent was launched using a deeplink that doesn't work well if the app is launched from a deeplink. Right now, I am adding an extra boolean to the intent to workaround the issue we have, but was wondering if there was something available in the framework/SDK to determine if a particular intent was the app start/launch intent.

NOTE: We are using jetpack navigation to handle incoming intents/deeplinks and to route deeplinks within the app. That is why in the snippet below you can see I am accessing the intent from `currentBackStackEntry`

Here is the code I've put in to support it so far:

In MainActivity onCreate

```
        intent.putExtra(KEY_IS_APP_CREATED_INTENT, true)
```

In our UI logic code

```
val isAppCreationIntent = navController.currentBackStackEntry?.arguments
    ?.parcelable<Intent>(KEY_DEEP_LINK_INTENT)
    ?.getBooleanExtra(KEY_IS_APP_CREATED_INTENT, false) ?: false
```

I logged a bug/feature request to provide this capability here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/265981498

Comment: Set a breakpoint and enable "wait for debugger". Then open the app and attach the debugger to debug the app start: https://source.android.com/docs/core/tests/debug/gdb?hl=en#app-startup

Comment: I need a solution that will work on apps installed from the play store

Comment: Why? You can start the app via deeplinks from Android Studio as well. Is there more to your problem?

Comment: This logic needs to execute in the app while it is out in the field on customer devices at runtime.